# disparador para insert mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

estoy realizando un disparador en mysql para que al momento de cambiarle el estado a un campo de un producto este se inserte en otra tabla que seria catalogo_producto, llevo un dia la verdad tratando de sacarlo pero me lanza errores con las claves foraneas, espero que me ayuden esta son las tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es poder realizar un disparador que al momento de hacer una actualización del campo estado_producto_id me realice una inserción en la tabla catalogos_productos.
este es mi disparador:

```js
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pro_a_catalogo AFTER UPDATE 
ON productos FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.estado_producto_id != 1 THEN 
INSERT INTO productos_catalogos(producto_id,nombre,descripcion,foto,marca_id,modelo,year,categoria_id) 
VALUES (NEW.producto_id,NEW.nombre,NEW.descripcion,NEW.foto,NEW.marca_id,NEW.modelo,NEW.year,NEW.categoria_id); 
END IF; 
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

el drama es que me esta tirando problemas con las fk, al momento de crearlo no me deja, pero si le quito el campo producto_id me deja crear el disparador, luego al momento de hacer el update me arroja el siguiente problema ( sin el campo producto_id)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna idea o corrección? la verdad llevo un día tratando de solucionarlo. gracias de ante mano

Comment: New es sobre la tabla productos? entonces ahi no existe el campo producto_id. deberias usar el campo new.id como producto_id

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono inmediatamente amigo eres un dios <3

Comment: Podemos decir que fue solamente un error tipografico y la cerramos?